# ReportContent doesn't work correct in acra

Tags: android, acra

G'day, there!

I've added acra for have information about application craches. The first of all, I tried to customize report content (I need ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.LOGCAT).

```
@ReportsCrashes(
formKey = "dXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXQ", 
customReportContent = {ReportField.PHONE_MODEL, ReportField.LOGCAT}
)
```

After I've added permissions android.permission.READ_LOGS and android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE. As the result, LOGCAT is writing to PHOME_MODEL at all...

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Same problem. And ACRA works if i load apk directly from eclipse, but if i export package in a apk file, then error occurs: NosuchField PHONEMODEL. I imported library and added proguard acra config

Comment: Seems you can't customize report field for Google Docs Spreadsheet. Just don't specify anything. Just remove customReportContent, and columns and data match correctly

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your own site or one of those paid services that gives you CouchDB space(or alternativly other backends if you have a website) if you want to customize the report content